# Is the transitive closure of a circular graph reflexive?

Tags: graph-theory

I feel like it is, but couldn't find anything online to support it - suppose the set A={a,b,c} and the relation set R={(a,b),(b,c),(c,a)}, would the transitive closure be reflexive (ie contain (a,a), (b,b) and (c,c)) since you can go from a back to a going all the way around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, you can get from any vertex to any vertex, so the transitive closure is a complete graph with a loop at each vertex.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case but then images like this http://anh.cs.luc.edu/363/notes/TransitiveClosure.png didn't show the creation of the reflexive relations.

Comment: @Harvey: You’re welcome. They clutter up the picture, so they might have been left out with a comment to that effect. Or the author might simply have been a bit sloppy.